# Looking for example of particular type of measure space on general topological saces

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space with non-trivial topology  (i.e. having at least one non empty proper open set) , does there exist a measure space $(X,\mathcal M, \mu)$ such that every open set (hence every Borel set) of $X$ is in $\mathcal M$ , $\infty >\mu(X)>0$ and there is a non empty open set $A$ in $X$  such that   $\mu(A)=0$   ?

Comment: Suspiciously easy. Just let $\mu$ be prescribed by $M\mapsto 0$ for every $M\in\mathcal M$.

Comment: @drhab : sorry for the confusion , I have edited

Comment: Now let $x\in X$ and let $\mu$ be prescribed by $M\mapsto1$ if $x\in M$ and $M\mapsto0$ otherwise. Then you can take $A=X-\{x\}$. It is open if the space is $T_1$. Extra condition $X$ itself is not a singleton.

Comment: @drhab : uh I see .... so then we don't even need $T_1$  , it is enough to have that at least one singleton is closed . But what happens if the space does not have this property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a non-empty open proper subset of $X$  and let $x\in A^c$.

(This is possible whenever the topology is not indiscrete.)

Prescribe $\mu$ on $\mathcal M$ by $M\mapsto 1_M(x)$.

Evidently $\mu(A)=0$ and $\mu(X)=1$.